# How do I launch a new form and return to it after the new form is closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

If my user clicks a button, I would like to launch a new Form.
Then when the user closes the second form, I would like to return back to the initial form.

```
var appLaunch = new App();
appLaunch.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Could anyone please help me? My code doesn't allow me to return back to where I left off when I close the second form

Comment: Do you have any reason to hide first form and not show the second one modally?

Answer (score 3):

To create a new form `appLaunch` you can use:

```
var appLaunch = new App();
appLaunch.Show(this);
this.Hide();
```

Then add this code on [`FormClosed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `appLaunch`

```
private void appLaunch_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {

   this.Owner.Show();
}
```

Comment: If form1 opens form2 and that opens forms3 and finally we open form4. If we close form 4, will that open form3? how will form4 know about form3? you wrote "yourform.show()"

Comment: @softwareisfun It seems you didn't see my update(13 minutes ago). There isn't ant yourform.show()

Answer (score 0):

The `hide()` function just temporarily removes the form from the display.

The `close()` function removed the form from memory.

So if you want to go back to form1 after showing form2, just don't `close` form1.  You could `hide` it, but you wouldn't have to.  Just `hide` form2 when you're wanting to return to form1.